# what is a more efficient way to start a new line after 10 integers per line in java?

Tags: java, arrays

The way i tried to do it isn't efficient or work on i reverse my array.

```
public static void reverseArray(int[] array) throws IOException
{
int i = array.length - 1;
System.out.println("\nPrinting Reversed Array:");

while(i >= 0)
{
  System.out.printf("%5d", array[i]);
  i--;
  if(i == 10 ||i == 20)
    System.out.printf("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be doing

```
if(i%10==0){
   System.out.printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @CalvinTeng accept the answer, so it helps others who look for same problem.
clicking on the 'correct tick ' to left of answer does that